# Viber install problem on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux

Tags: ubuntu, viber, ubuntu-20.04

I've tried [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-viber-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) description. Installation using snap was successfull, but after configuring Viber, the following error message came:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
sh: 1: xdg-mime: not found
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /snap/viber-mtd/17/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /snap/viber-mtd/17/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
[15972:15972:0515/162634.438831:FATAL:credentials.cc(155)] Check failed: NamespaceUtils::DenySetgroups(). : Permission denied
#0 0x7fa98b6aa11e base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7fa98b6babde logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7fa98b6bae99 logging::ErrnoLogMessage::~ErrnoLogMessage()
#3 0x7fa98c3acf7c sandbox::(anonymous namespace)::SetGidAndUidMaps()
#4 0x7fa98c3ad5d5 sandbox::Credentials::CanCreateProcessInNewUserNS()
#5 0x7fa98b31dde5 content::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#6 0x7fa98afd0314 content::BrowserMainLoop::EarlyInitialization()
#7 0x7fa98afd4190 content::BrowserMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#8 0x7fa98add9d19 QtWebEngineCore::WebEngineContext::WebEngineContext()
#9 0x7fa98addb135 QtWebEngineCore::WebEngineContext::current()
#10 0x7fa98ad78931 QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::defaultContext()
#11 0x7fa993091618 QQuickWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()
#12 0x0000006ac8bf ApplicationPrivate::preRunningInitialization()
#13 0x0000006a6504 ViberApplication::start()
#14 0x00000067e25b ViberMain()
#15 0x7fa987d7e830 __libc_start_main
#16 0x0000004d7047 <unknown>

Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /snap/viber-mtd/17/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /snap/viber-mtd/17/opt/viber/resources. Trying parent directory...
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
PulseAudioService: pa_context_connect() failed
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
PulseAudioService: pa_context_connect() failed
Assertion 'pthread_mutex_unlock(&m->mutex) == 0' failed at pulsecore/mutex-posix.c:108, function pa_mutex_unlock(). Aborting.
```

After it, I've removed it, and tried the second method (install from deb package). But the referred libssl package was not found.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location of the libssl package was not correct.

Visit the http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/ site, and download one of the libssl file. At the moment I visited, there was a **libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb** file, I've downloaded.

And after it:

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

If there is some dependency requirements, also run:

```
apt-get install -f
```

And it will work :)

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 20.04, but first step fails. First step returns "libssl1.0-dev conflicts with libssl-dev  libssl-dev:amd64 (version 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2) is present and installed."
I was able to authenticate, sync and send messages.
The Snap version of Viber, Viber-mtd, died after authentication attempt.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Snap, you need to allow it permission to use the audio systems. There is a command line way to do it (snap connections) but I used the Software app, found the Viber snap and clicked "Permissions".

Answer (score 0):

Easy-peasy way to install it - type in your terminal:

```
snap install viber-unofficial
```

thats all :) run and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the two versions included with 20.04 - neither worked, couldn't establish a connection with my smartphone. Then I tried downloading the .deb software direct from the Rakuten.Viber website. That appeared to get a little further, but not much. Then I happened to leave my computer on for many days, ran many programs, and just before deleting the Viber program, thought I would give it one last try. And it worked!  I resynced the chats - all OK :-)

So - maybe something I ran set up the computer so the "initial connection" phase would work. Who knows. We'll see whether it continues to work after I reboot my desktop...